# PHP/Bootstrap Page Pagination

Tags: php, html

I'm an amateur coder in PHP and bootstrap 4.

Have recently migrated my websites from Joomla/WordPress because I want more control over what my sites do. I have a fairly static website that displays the ten most recent articles and want to display blog posts in groups of ten.

> Problem statement:

I have a website with thirty plus articles which displays the first 10 pages of blog articles (the most recent) ... the articles are not contained in a database, my PHP code looks for them in the "articles" folder with all articles names "article0001" to "article00xx" etc. (sequentially). I can easily create a series of pages that display articles 11-20, 21-30 and so on but that's a really ugly solution IMO.

I am trying to make a single page that can display pages 1 to 10, 11-20 etc. but does so at the click of a button ...

Hopefully test script below makes some sense and gives an idea of what I'm trying to do. In essence (assuming going towards older articles) this means:

Drop range limiting variables by 10
Check variables are still between 1 and total number of articles (adjust if necessary).
Display new set of articles.

```
        //
        // Set intial variables based on number of articles
        //
        $i = 0;
        do {
            $i++;
            $filename = "./articles/article" . substr("000$i", strlen ("000$i")-4) . ".php";
        } while(file_exists($filename));
        $articles = $i - 1;

        //
        // $articles to max articles
        // Set $max = $articles;
        // Set $min = $articles - 9;
        //
        $max = $articles;
        $min = $articles - 9;

        echo "Display articles from $max down to $min</br>";

        $i = $max;
        while($i >= $min) {
            $filename = "./articles/article" . substr("000$i", strlen ("000$i")-4) . ".php";
            echo "$filename </br>";
            $i = $i - 1;
        }

        // If BACK:
            // Set $min = $min-10
            // Set $max = $min+9

        // If FORWARD:
            // Set $max = $max+10
            // Set $min = $max+9

        // If $min < 1:
            // Set $min = 1
        // If $max < $articles:
            // Set $max = $articles

        //
    ?>

    <!-- Pagination -->
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">
        <li class="page-item">
            <?php 
                echo "<a class=\"page-link\" href=\"$prevfile\"> &larr; Prev </a>";
            ?>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <?php 
                echo "<a class=\"page-link\" href=\"$nextfile\"> Next &rarr; </a>";
            ?> 
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You can use jquery datatables

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Hold on ... I think I may have found a way to do what I want! I'll post back if/when I sort it :)

Comment: Hi everyone. Thanks for the suggestions/comments ... I have now managed to sort out my problem, by passing parameters.